# how do we get the android:description of an apk in java?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, apk

I've got a problem to get the android:description of an apk : I have to get it in java in order to put this information in my database when loading the apk. I get the reference encoded, using aapt -l a x.apk | grep  android:description. 
In the apk unzipped this reference is, in the manifest.xml an access to strings.xml of the value-fr (example for value-

java -jar \apktool.jar d \x.apk

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="330" android:versionName="4.0.3-239410" package="com.google.android.talk"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
…
    <application android:label="@string/app_label" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_google_talk" android:name="TalkApp" android:taskAffinity="android.task.googletalk" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
…
        <service android:name="com.google.android.videochat.VideoChatService" android:description="@string/videochatservice_description"> android:permission="com.google.android.talk.permission.VIDEO_CHAT_SERVICE">
</service>
…
    </application>
</manifest>
```

then in res\values-fr\strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
…
    <string name="videochatservice_description">"Talk Service."</string>
…
</resources>
```

My goal is to get the string "Talk Service" in java.

By now I don't think it's possible to do what I want without using apktool. If anyone has a faster solution, I'll take a look at it. Let's say we use this apktool command : java -jar \apktool.jar d .apk  using ProcessBuilder. What is the simplest way to get the info ? I use sax to parse xml.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're asking. If you just want to read the string value from the resources, this will do it.

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.string.videochatservice_description);
```